# Selenium web element "window-size=" is not working in Automation with "--headless=new" chrome on Linux System

Tags: java, linux, windows, selenium-webdriver

Observation:

1. If we add any resolution like options.addArguments("window-size=1600,1200") it is not working for linux system.
2. Default small resolution screens  like 800x600 are capture in screenshot folder with "--headless=new" chrome

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is issue with options in chromedriver for headless.
Could you try the alternate method to set size

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1600,1200));
```